# Iterator implementation is only reading first token in string?

Tags: java, iterator, token

for this program, I need to implement a token iterator that scans from a string and stores a token if it is valid. This seems like an easy process, but my code is only returning the first valid token within the string. Do I need to call hasNext(); in a different location in the next() method?

Here is my code:

```
public class TokenIter implements Iterator<String>{

    //input line to be tokenized
    private String line;

    // the next Token, null if no next Token
    private String nextToken;

    //Edit
    private Scanner scan;

    public TokenIter(String line){
        this.line = line;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        //Edit
        scan = new Scanner(line);
            if(scan.hasNext()){
                nextToken = scan.next();
                return true;
            }
            scan.next();
            nextToken = null;
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        if(!hasNext()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        else{
            if(nextToken.equals("true")){
                return nextToken;
            }
            if(nextToken.equals("false")){
                return nextToken;
            }
            if(nextToken.equals("or")){
                return nextToken;
            }
            if(nextToken.equals("and")){
                return nextToken;
            }
            if(nextToken.equals("not")){
                return nextToken;
            }
            if(nextToken.equals("(")){
                return nextToken;
            }
            if(nextToken.equals(")")){
                return nextToken;
            }
        }
        return "";      
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String line;
        args = Debug.init(args);
        if(args.length>0)
            line = args[0];
        else
            line = " not (true or error false) @# $% ";
        System.out.println("line: [" + line + "]");
        TokenIter tokIt = new TokenIter(line);
        while(tokIt.hasNext()){
            System.out.println("next token: [" + tokIt.next() + "]");
        }
    }
```

Here is my output of the running program:

```
line: [ not (true or error false) @# $% ]
next token: [not]
next token: [not]
next token: [not]
next token: [not]
next token: [not]
next token: [not]
```

This is my desired output:

```
line: [ not (true or error false) @# $% ]
next token: [not]
next token: [(]
next token: [true]
next token: [or]
next token: [false]
next token: [)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `hasNext()` method is incorrect, you are scanning the `line` with every call so you will always return the first token:

```
 @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
            if(scan.hasNext()){
                nextToken = scan.next();
                return true;
            }
            scan.next();
            nextToken = null;
            return false;
```

Solution:
The variable `scan` needs to become a class variable so you keep the state between invocations of `hasNext()`.

Comment: That makes sense. However, line is the input string that needs to be tokenized. How could I skip past the first token to the next token in the second method call?

Comment: made that change, see my edit. still receiving the same output

Comment: @Lewis the line `scan = new Scanner(line);` needs to be in the constructor.

Comment: I am not getting any output now. Just blank tokens. Something bigger is going on here, quite the annoying bug. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

As already commented, scanner should be initialized inside the constructor.

Also `TokenIter.hasNext()` is not the place to set the TokenIter.token, should only return true or false if `TokenIter.scan.hasNext()`. Assignment should be placed inside `TokenIter.next()`

additionally, `Scanner` class uses a delimiter (space by default) so you should wait to catch `"(true"` as one token. Probably you would like to catch words start with `"("` and split them in two tokens inside the overriden `TokenIter.next()`